# Python regex match for exact number

Tags: python, regex

I have to find only two digit numbers in this case 32, but it is matching and printing 323, 32222,

Code:

```
import re

s = """32 M 32 L 32 S 32 K 324 J 32555 A 32222 B 8888
```

32 small again 32 324 567
323 yes 32 else again not 323 32 32-123"""

```
pattern = "32" # Also tried with "32/s" but if 32 present at end it does not match and also tried with "32{2}" still not working
# As per below answers, i used pattern = "\\b32\\b"
# But it is also matching 32-123, in my case only 32 must be matched 
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(result)
print(len(result))
```

Expected Output:
['32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32'] # length is 8 because string s contains 8 times 32 digits
8

Comment: what is the expected output here, is that just `['32']`?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pattern = "\\b32\\b"` \b - is a word bounder and you should use double \

Comment: Not a python expert, why the double `\\` is needed?

Comment: Because single slash is used as escape sequence character and hence to read a slash you have to prefix it with another slash. Other choice can be to use raw strings if this feels confusing.

Comment: This answers looks correct what if number starts like something 32-123, it is matching but in my case it should not match

Comment: It won't match, because here \b is used. [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) you can read some detailed information how it works. If you new at regular expressions there is an [excellent book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/introducing-regular-expressions/9781449338879/). It's possible to read it during for couple of evenings. It's really useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use the regex `r'\b\d{2}\b'` to get two-digit numbers separated by the word boundaries.

[image]

Comment: OP wants to get exact match [`32`]. Other numbers are NOT important. Please, read OP's question again.

Comment: According to OP, "I have to find only two digit numbers in this case 32"

Comment: OP stated: *Expected Output: ['32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32'] # length is 8 because string s contains 8 times 32 digits*

Comment: I think it's not clear. So, let the OP decide.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pattern = r'\b32\b'
```

The `'r'` at the start of the pattern string designates a python "`raw`" string which passes through backslashes without change.

`\b` allows you to perform a “`whole words only`” search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`.

Comment: What a legend, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can apply word boundary in your pattern like this:

```
import re

s = """32 M 32 L 32 S 32 K 324 J 32555 A 32222 B 8888
32 small again 32 324 567
323 yes 32 else again not 323 32"""

pattern = r"\b32\b" 
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(result)
```

To search any two digit numbers below pattern can be used:

```
pattern = r"\b\d\d\b"
```